# DisplayPort produces no sound across HDMI adapter on HP8740w

Tags: sound, hp, hdmi, displayport

I have a new (refurbished) HP8740w notebook that came with Windows 7 installed, and on which the DP operates as expected - I plug in an HDMI adapter and get video and sound just fine on the HDMI TV.

However, running Xubuntu 16.04.3 with the HWE kernel, I get the video just fine and no sound.  In fact, I can't even see a digital sound option in the controls.

I went through about half the steps in the Ubuntu sound troubleshooting page (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting) but so far I haven't found a clue.

20:04 [admar@mar-HP8740w:~] $ sudo aplay -l
[sudo] password for admar:
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 0: 92HD75B3X5 Analog [92HD75B3X5 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

I won't show the full list of lib/modules drivers as it is fairly
extensive (unless someone thinks the answer might be there...).

20:06 [admar@mar-HP8740w:~] $ sudo lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset
High Definition Audio (rev 06)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High
Definition Audio
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
Memory at d7420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
20:07 [admar@mar-HP8740w:~] $ sudo lsmod | grep snd
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_codec_idt      57344  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_hda_codec         126976  4
snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_core           81920  5
snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102400  5
snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    77824  20
snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd

Here is what pavucontrol lists for the configuration options for the
sound with the headset (speakers) unplugged:

Analog Stereo Duplex
Analog Stereo Output
Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input
Analog Surround 4.0 Output (unplugged)
Analog Stereo Input
Off

Al of this was with the DP-HDMI adapter plugged in and connected to the HDMI TV.

For the record, the sound through the notebook's built-in speakers with the Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input was much more brilliant and sounded pretty decent for laptop speakers, but that's not an acceptable substitute or solution.  When connected to the TV and set for the Analog Surround sound, the speakers go silent.

I also tried to do the sound reinstall with aptitude, but for some
reason aptitude can't find the generic kernel image or modules for the
installed kernel (Linux mar-HP8740w 4.10.0-32-generic#36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 9 09:19:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux).

I don't really need the HWE kernel if that's the problem, but I have
no clue (drivers have never been my area of specialty).

Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Comment: This one? https://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-HP-EliteBook-8740w-Mobile-Workstation.42252.0.html If so you need to install Nvidia drivers. Open Additional Drivers, select the recommended version, apply and reboot.

Comment: That's the one.  I already have the Nvidia drivers installed, v340.102.